# Composite function question

Tags: functions, function-and-relation-composition

Given $f :\{1,2 ,4 \} \rightarrow \{a,b,c,d\} $ and $g : \{a,b,c\} \rightarrow \{1, 2, 4\}$ where $f = \{(1,b),(2,d),(4,d)\}$ and $g = \{(a,1), (b,2), (c,4)\}$.

What is $g \circ f$?

As far as I know the image of $f$ needs to be subset of the domain of $g$, and in this case it isn't. So what is then $g \circ  f$, is it an empty set or can't the computation be even obtained? Thanks.

Comment: Just follow the definition.

Comment: You are correct, and [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_composition#Properties).  So indeed, $g\circ f = \varnothing$ in this case, and in most interpretations, or general. the given  composition, essentially does not exist.

Comment: By the way, CupOfCoffee, this is a fine question.  I don't know why it would have been downvoted.  You're clear in your question about how to think about $g\circ f$, given all the details you've given in the question, and it is clear you have thought about it, and explained precisely where you stuck.

Answer (score 3):

The two functions $f$ and $g$ cannot be composed as $g\circ f$ since $g\circ f(2)$ and $g\circ f(4)$ are not defined.

So we say the composed function $g\circ f$ $\color{red}{\text{does not exist}}$ for these two functions $f$ and $g$.

However, you can define the restricted function $g\circ f\Big|_{\{ 1\}}=\{ (1,2)\}$ by restricting the domain of $f$ to $\{ 1\}$.

Answer (score 0):

$g \circ f $ is a function from $\{1,2,4\} $ to $\{1,2,4\} $.

Let us be explicit
$$g\circ f (1)=g (f(1))=g (b)=2$$

$$g\circ f (2)=g (f (2))=g (d)$$

but $g (d )$  is not defined.

Thus $g\circ f (2) $  does not exist.

You can finish.

What is the domain of $g\circ f $.